# feign.FeignException$BadRequest: [400 Bad Request] during [GET] to [http://cameraservice/api/cameras?id.in=11&id.in=12&

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-cloud, api-gateway, openfeign

I need to get a response from another service, I do it FeignClient, when more than 100 ids are passed in the request parameters, this error appears. If less than 100 it works fine.

my FeignClient:

```
@FeignClient(
    name = "${application.camera-service.service-id}",
    url = "${application.camera-service.url}"
)
public interface FeignCameraServiceClient {

    @RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        path = "${application.camera-service.path}?id.in={ids}"
    )
    List<CameraResponse> getCameraList(@PathVariable(name = "ids") List<Integer> idList);

}
```

its method in another service which receives the request:

```
@GetMapping("/cameras")
public ResponseEntity<List<CameraDTO>> getAllCameras(CameraCriteria criteria) {
    log.debug("REST request to get Cameras by criteria: {}", criteria);

    List<CameraDTO> entityList = cameraQueryService.findByCriteria(criteria, Sort.by("id"));

    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(entityList);
}
```

I tried to increase parameter in application.yml in both services:

```
server:
  max-http-header-size: 100KB
```

but it didn't help. I get error:

> Internal Server Error feign.FeignException$BadRequest: [400 Bad
> Request] during [GET] to
> [http://cameraservice/api/cameras?id.in=11&id.in=12&id.in=14&id.in=15&...

[image]

dependency:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
```